# JPA subselect em MANYTOMANY

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com java+jpa+mysql
porem agora estou com uma dúvida que ainda não consegui encontrar a resposta...
Dada as tabelas e entidades abaixo, gostaria de montar uma jpql para realizar a seguinte consulta em SQL nativa:

```
SELECT * FROM politico po
where po.idpolitico not in ( SELECT mu.idpolitico FROM info_muni_politico mu  )
```

Tentei montar a seguinte JPQL mas da erro na execução:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT p FROM Politico p ");
        sql.append("WHERE p.id  NOT IN ( ");
        sql.append("SELECT p2.politicos FROM InfoMunicipio p2 )");
        Query q = em.createQuery(sql.toString());
        List<Politico> resultList = q.getResultList();
```

Erro:

> 10:05:49,637 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (default task-20) SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

Alguém sabe como montar essa jpql?

Entidades Mapeadas

```
@Entity
@Table(name="info_municipio")
public class InfoMunicipio {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idinfo_municipio")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="num_habitantes")
    private Integer numeroHabitantes;
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name="info_muni_politico", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idinfo_municipio"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idpolitico") )
    private List<Politico> politicos;

    //getters e setters 
}




@Entity
@Table(name="politico")
public class Politico {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idpolitico")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    //getters e setters
}
```

Tabelas do banco

```
CREATE TABLE `info_municipio` (
  `idinfo_municipio` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num_habitantes` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idinfo_municipio`)
)

CREATE TABLE `info_muni_politico` (
  `idinfo_municipio` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idpolitico` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idinfo_municipio`,`idpolitico`),
  CONSTRAINT `muni_info_muni_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`idinfo_municipio`) REFERENCES `info_municipio` (`idinfo_municipio`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `politico_info_muni_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`idpolitico`) REFERENCES `politico` (`idpolitico`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE `politico` (
  `idpolitico` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idpolitico`)
)
```

Comment: O erro que você postou, é apenas um trecho de warning, poderia compartilhar a stacktrace inteira pra eu tentar ti ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisaria da stack trace inteira para te dizer exatamente o motivo do erro, mas adianto que sua consulta JPQL tem um problema.

Em sua consulta JPQL, você está querendo comparar um ID (`p.id  NOT IN`) com uma lista (`SELECT p2.politicos`). Isto não dará certo.

Corrigindo a consulta, você poderia fazer desta maneira:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT p FROM Politico p ");
        sql.append("WHERE p.id NOT IN ( ");
        sql.append("SELECT p2.id FROM InfoMunicipio infoMun )");
        sql.append("JOIN infoMun.politicos p2 )");
        Query q = em.createQuery(sql.toString());
        List<Politico> resultList = q.getResultList();
```

Infelizmente, vai exigir um JOIN a mais (se comparada a consulta nativa equivalente).